# GUID as FK Non-Clustered Index SQL Server 2017

Tags: entity-framework-core, guid, sql-server-2017

I am designing entirely a system that will work in both connected and unconnected modes and I am currently modeling the DB. By the way, I am using ASP NET Core, EF Core 2.2 and SQL Server 2017. After reading the relevant documentation and consulting other questions in forums like this, I have decided to use the following approach:

PK: Guid, Non-Clustered Index

```
builder.HasKey(e => e.Id)
       .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false); //Reduce fragmentation.
```

Now, as I understand that EF Core will try to add the Guid as sequential, I have set the default value to NEWID() for security reasons:

```
builder.Property(e => e.Id)
       .HasColumnName($"{typeof(TEntity).Name}Id")
       .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
       .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
```

So that the table is not a heap, I used the second column of type Int to be the Clustered Index. It is also Identity and Unique:

```
builder.HasIndex(e => e.ClusteredIndex)
       .ForSqlServerIsClustered(true)
       .IsUnique();

builder.Property(e => e.ClusteredIndex)
       .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()
       .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

My question is how performance is affected by the use of GUID as FK? I have some thoughts on this but I prefer to ask.
I thought of using the Int (Clustered Index) as FK, but the value of this field could be repeated when a client works offline. So I decided not to synchronize it and configure it as
Unique, so I can only use the GUID as FK in relationships. 
I understand that a Non-Clustered Index will point to the Clustered Index of the table.

To load the data I use eager load and filters or projections. The number of rows per table will not exceed one million.

What's wrong with this approach? How could it be improved?

Thanks in advance.